# SwiftUI: attach an animation to a transition

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, animation, swiftui

According to the Apple documentation we should be able to attach an animation directly to a transition. For example:

```
.transition(AnyTransition.slide.animation(.linear))
```

documentation for the method:

```
extension AnyTransition {

    /// Attach an animation to this transition.
    public func animation(_ animation: Animation?) -> AnyTransition
}
```

says:

> Summary
>
> Attaches an animation to this transition.

But I can't manage to make it work. Take a look at this minimum viable example (you can copy-paste it and try yourself):

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnimationTest: View {
    @State private var show = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if show {
                Color.green
                    .transition(AnyTransition.slide.animation(.linear))
            } else {
                Color.yellow
                    .transition(AnyTransition.slide.animation(.linear))
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.show.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("CHANGE VIEW!")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct AnimationTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnimationTest()
    }
}
```

As you can see no animation happens at all. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I ran into this as well and filed a bug report. Still doesn't seem to be working in Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the boolean toggling within a `withAnimation()` closure:

```
withAnimation {
    self.show.toggle()
}
```

Tested the transition working on Xcode 11.2.1 while on the **simulator**; the Canvas doesn't preview it.

Please note that animations/transitions applied directly to a view have an effect on that particular view and its children. Moreover, according to the docs:

```
func animation(Animation?) -> View
```

> Applies the given animation to all animatable values within the view.

Since the animatable value, in this case the Bool toggle enabling the transition, is external to the Color views, it must be animated explicitly from where it's set in the button's action. Alternatively, one can effectively attach the transition directly to the target views, but apply the animation to their container, thus enabling interpolation of changes to `show`. So, this also achieves the desired result:

```
struct AnimationTest: View {
    @State private var show = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if show {
                Color.green
                    .transition(.slide)
            } else {
                Color.yellow
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.show.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("CHANGE VIEW!")
            })
        }
        .animation(.linear)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know that using explicit animations will fix the problem. But the issue here is that an animation can be attached directly to a transition (according to the Apple documentation). But for some reasons, at least in the example above, they don't seem to work in some cases and I was trying to understand why.

Comment: I think I came to some understanding about the situation after completing the latest technique project about SwiftUI's layout system on Hacking With Swift https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-layout-works-in-swiftui, and reading again through the docs on animations. Please see my updated answer.